# UITableView Accessory Button Segue Not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having big problems learning how to pass data from the cell accessory button to the detail view controller with segues.  If I tap the cell the data is passed to the detail view controller in a  `NSString *selectedItem;` and the label on the other view updates with the word that was in the cell -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
        }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
                destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            }
        }
```

And i connect a segue on the storyboard from the cell to the detail view with a name "toDeatil" It works when i click the cell it goes to the detail screen, but if i put

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
    }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
        }
    }
```

Almost exactly the same but from the `accessorybutton` and I connect a segue on the storyboard from the cell `accessorybutton` to the detail view with a name "`toDetail`" when I click the cell it goes to the detail screen, but the information is not there, the label dosent get filled out or just uses the first cell detail all the time.

I've tried heaps of combinations.  I've tried making my own accessory button, a `UIButton` in a custom cell but it just uses the first cells details all the time.

The goal is to get `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` going to one view and `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` going to a different view but I need to tell `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` what cell was pressed.

Hope this makes sence.

Thank you

Comment: Send here [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self]; instead of "self" something like [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] and the get this value in prepareForSegue

Comment: Where do i get this value in the prepareForSegue?

Comment: NSNumber *sent = (NSNumber *)sender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `indexPath` as `sender` to the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:indexPath];//IndexPath as sender
}
```

And in your `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
        //Detect sender class and act accordingly
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [sender isKindOfClass:[NSIndexPath class]] ? (NSIndexPath*)sender : [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to implement **accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath**.

When **prepareForSegue** is fired from an accessory view, the **sender:(id)sender** parameter is set to the **UITableViewCell** which contains the accessory view. You can then ask the table view for the index of that cell (not the selected index).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"] && [sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` will return a NSIndexPath only if the ROW is tapped, not when the accessory button is tapped.

In `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`, you will need to pass `indexPath.row` to the prepareForSegue method manually. Try this:

```
NSInteger selectedRow;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) 
    {
        DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow] name];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error saying "expected identifier" for this line =
destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]] name];

Comment: actually it does work, is see now an accidental double ]] in the code.  Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

What about, if you drive state of what is selected on application delegate! Answer of Raul Juarez do the work, but the target of sender parameter is other!

I have an app that use UITableView, and i need to know what item was touched on accessory button in above screen!

To manage this scenery, i have one property on application delegate, that i update when i touch table view accessory button; so in the next screen, i can retrieve the item touched reading the property of application delegate.

In general, i use de application delegate to code model application (dividing necessary class), so views instances only interact with this model to update necessary states! what i do is focus view work independent of model work!

Maybe some like this:

```
// Property on Application Delegate
@propety (atomic,readwrite) NSIndexPath* indexTapped;

// Method on UITableViewDelegate instance
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIMyAppDelegate* model = (UIMyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication shared] delegate];
    model.indexTapped = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
}

// Method on another View Controller
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIMyAppDelegate* model = (UIMyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication shared] delegate];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexTapped = model.indexSelected;
        DrugDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.selectedItem = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
    }
}
```